# Associating job with job class

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

I'm attempting to create a job using DBMS_SCHEDULER in an Oracle 11g DB but having some trouble setting the job class attribute.  I have already looked in the SYS schema and there is a job class named "SCHED$_LOG_ON_ERRORS_CLASS" that only outputs to the log if a job fails, which is what I want instead of having it log every time the job succeeds.  Here is the script I am using to create the job:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
        job_name => 'DIRXML.CHECK_EVENTLOG', 
        job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE', 
        job_action => 'DIRXML.P_Check_Eventlog', 
        job_class => 'DIRXML.SCHED$_LOG_ON_ERRORS_CLASS',
        repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=30', 
        enabled => TRUE
    );
END;
/
```

The script will execute without errors if I remove the job_class attribute but when I add it I get the following error:

> ORA-27476: "SYS.SCHED$_LOG_ON_ERRORS_CLASS" does not exist ORA-06512:
>   at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 124 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER",
>   line 271 ORA-06512: at line 2

The only thing I could think of is that permissions aren't set up correctly for my user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there wasn't a public execute grant on that specific job class, which explains why it wasn't finding it.

Comment: +1 for answering your own question. If you accept this answer as well then people in the future know that this solved the issue.

Comment: Yup, have to wait 2 days, though. :)

Comment: Ach, fair 'nuff. Never been in that situation :-).